# What are Linear and Non-Linear Features of an image in the context of Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, feature-selection, relu

What features of image are linear or non-linear, any example ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "image features are non-linear" and "non-linear kernel". Please, edit your post to include the excerpt from the source where you heard or saw these terms/expressions (so provide some context).